# How to exit a script (end it's run) with specific code when certain statement is false?

Tags: bash, exit-code

I want my script to drop back to shell if the user is not root and i want the exit code to be 5

```
who=`whoami`
if [ echo $who != "root"];
        then exit (5)
else
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just get rid of the parentheses: `exit 5`. Also, leave a space before the `]` and no `echo`: `if [ $who != "root" ];` (space before `]`). Voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
who=`whoami`
if [ $who != "root" ]; then 
    exit 5
else
```

Comment: backticks for `whoami` ;)

Comment: True, thanks for correcting @gniourf_gniourf.  Editing to fix it.  Also I saw that you edited your comment with all explanations as I was writing this.  +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of `$(...)` which would run the command in a subshell thereby eliminating the need for extra variable to store the effective uid.

```
if [ $(whoami) != "root" ]; then
  exit 5;
else
  ...
fi
```

Alternatively, you can use `id` to get the same information:

```
if [ $(id -un) != "root" ]; then
  exit 5;
else
  ...
fi
```

Comment: Might as well use `(( UID!=0 )) && exit 5` directly: no external processes!

Comment: For root one doesn't need to figure the numeric GID so why not!

Answer (score 0):

vinoqadhikary's answer is correct.  gniourf_gniourf's comment also corrected a problem in the answer given.

why your code had problems:

The `[`  is actually an external command on my system:  `/usr/bin/[`  Since it is a command, it wants to have white space around it so the shell can parse it for you.

```
type [
```

will show you what you have on your system.

When you put something inside parenthesis like this:  `( stuff in here )`  two things to note:

```
stuff in here
```

will be executed as a command.  5 is not a command.

Next: if what you had for `stuff in here`
was a real command the shell understood, then the shell would have run it as a child process -- not what you intended.

Comment: in [tag:bash], `[` is _not_ an external command, it's a builtin: `help [` to be convinced.

Comment: Also, try `echo ( echo )`. The `echo` inside the parenthesis is a real command, but the line still yields an error.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - really?  I think not:  `$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

jim@jim-HP ~
$ which [
/usr/bin/[

Comment: I wrote `help [`. Because if you believe what you're saying you'll believe that `test`, `echo` and `printf` are external commands (`which test`, `which echo` and `which printf`)... Once again, in [tag:bash], `[` is a builtin as shown by `type [`. The command `which` doesn't have access to the [tag:bash] builtins.

Comment: You are correct. which does not see builtins.  If you think builtins are a fixed entity: [bash builtins](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/)

Comment: Your link is definitely beyond the scope of this post. But thanks, it looks like interesting information.